# how to monitor the web traffic from any browser in a PC using a Java App

Tags: java, url, browser, httprequest, monitor

I am working on a **JAVA application** to monitor the URLs requested from **any browser** on the PC .

I need your help in how to monitor the HTTP request especially the URL transmitted by any browser ( Firefox , chrome or internet explorer ).

**Thanks Guys**

Comment: You should have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/

Comment: Acting as an HTTP Proxy Server would be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy is indeed easiest because you get some high level information back. I wrote a java-based proxy server initially intended to authenticate against an NTLM proxy for git.

https://github.com/nablex/proxy